# How to set On Image and Off Image for UISwitch in storyBoard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, storyboard, uiswitch

I am working on UISwitch, i want to set on Image and off Image for UISwitch in storyboard but image is not set on switch.

I try this : 
[image]

I want to create like this:

[image]

Not like this --->

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if storyboard did not working perfectly then try to set image throw coding part.

Comment: Can you elaborate `it is not working`?

Comment: @Desdenova Please see the screen shot, i have already set on image in storyboard but nothing to do in work space area

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the switch on/off state programmatically and set image.

```
[YourSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(switchToggled:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    - (void) switchToggled:(id)sender {
        UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
        if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
            [switchControl setThumbTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb.png"]]];
        } else {
            [switchControl setThumbTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Thumb.png"]]];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This answer is not work for me. this code is change thumbnail image

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIButton in place of UISwitch as its useful and also time saving and easy to customise..

use image slicing for UIButton like you are using UISwitch
and set it as Background image like this

```
[cell.btnSwitch setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchOn"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.btnSwitch setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"switchOff"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```